How to Migrate Polkadot Pallet-Staking from Version 13 to 15? [updated]
I am currently working on migrating a Polkadot chain's pallet-staking module from version 13 directly to version 15. The current mainnet deployment have the pallet-staking running version 13, and I need to perform the migrations for testing purposes using try-runtime.
In the pallet-staking module, I've encountered a migration check as follows:
pub mod v14 {
    use super::*;

    #[frame_support::storage_alias]
    pub(crate) type OffendingValidators<T: Config> =
        StorageValue<Pallet<T>, Vec<(u32, bool)>, ValueQuery>;

    pub struct MigrateToV14<T>(core::marker::PhantomData<T>);
    impl<T: Config> OnRuntimeUpgrade for MigrateToV14<T> {
        fn on_runtime_upgrade() -> Weight {
            let in_code = Pallet::<T>::in_code_storage_version();
            let on_chain = Pallet::<T>::on_chain_storage_version();

            if in_code == 14 && on_chain == 13 {
                in_code.put::<Pallet<T>>();

                log!(info, "staking v14 applied successfully.");
                T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(1, 1)
            } else {
                log!(warn, "staking v14 not applied.");
                T::DbWeight::get().reads(1)
            }
        }

        #[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
        fn post_upgrade(_state: Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), TryRuntimeError> {
            frame_support::ensure!(
                Pallet::<T>::on_chain_storage_version() >= 14,
                "v14 not applied"
            );
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}

runtime code:
/// Runtime migrations
type Migrations = (
    pallet_staking::migrations::v14::MigrateToV14<Runtime>,
    pallet_staking::migrations::v15::MigrateV14ToV15<Runtime>,
    pallet_identity::migration::versioned::V0ToV1<Runtime, IDENTITY_MIGRATION_KEY_LIMIT>,
);

/// Executive: handles dispatch to the various modules.
pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    Migrations,
>;


When attempting to migrate from version 13 to version 14, this check fails because the current in_code is already 15.
Is there a recommended approach or workaround to perform a direct migration from pallet-staking version 13 to version 15, bypassing version 14? Or is there a specific method to handle this migration sequence?
Try-runtime logs:
[2024-10-10T18:14:47Z WARN  runtime::staking] [17564608]  staking v14 not applied.
[2024-10-10T18:14:47Z INFO  frame_support::migrations]  Pallet "Grandpa" VersionedMigration migrating storage version from 4 to 5.
[2024-10-10T18:14:47Z WARN  frame_support::migrations]  Pallet "Staking" VersionedMigration migration 14->15 can be removed; on-chain is already at StorageVersion(13).
[2024-10-10T18:14:47Z ERROR runtime::frame-support] Staking: On chain storage version StorageVersion(13) doesn't match in-code storage version StorageVersion(15).
[2024-10-10T18:14:47Z ERROR try-runtime] Detected multiple errors while executing `try_on_runtime_upgrade`:
[2024-10-10T18:14:47Z ERROR try-runtime] Other("v14 not applied")
[2024-10-10T18:14:47Z ERROR try-runtime] Other("On chain and in-code storage version do not match. Missing runtime upgrade?")


Thank you in advance for any insights or suggestions.

The question is, why is the current version already 15?

@AurevoirXavier because the version of pallet-staking is 15 at polkadot v1.12.0. I have added more information in the question. Could you please check?

So, the current version is 13.
You can't skip the 14 as the error log stated.
However, you can execute them at once.
Pseudo code:
pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    (ToV14, ToV15),
>;


I'm trying like this but getting the same error: type Migrations = (  pallet_staking::migrations::v14::MigrateToV14<Runtime>,  pallet_staking::migrations::v15::MigrateV14ToV15<Runtime>, );

May I have your code to take a look?

Added more code in the question. could you please check?
